# Tuning Infinispan for local MVCC HashMap

Tags: infinispan

I am new to Infinispan and basically stumbled over it whilst looking for an isolated MVCC HashMap for Java.

I am concerned that Infinispan may be somewhat heavy for what I need or that there may be a more performant way to achieve what I need with Infinispan. I don't need clustering or distribution, I just need the embedded Infinispan inside a single JVM.

At the moment I need a Map implementation which has transactions and *Repeatable Read* semantics, I currently have the following initialization code:

```
final ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.jmxStatistics().available(false);
builder.invocationBatching().enable();
builder.versioning().scheme(VersioningScheme.SIMPLE);
builder.versioning().enable();
builder.locking().concurrencyLevel(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2);
builder.locking().writeSkewCheck(true);
builder.transaction().locking().isolationLevel(IsolationLevel.REPEATABLE_READ);
builder.transaction().lockingMode(LockingMode.OPTIMISTIC);
builder.transaction().transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL);

final DefaultCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(builder.build());
final Cache<String, String> cache = cacheManager.getCache();
final TransactionManager transactionManager = cache.getAdvancedCache().getTransactionManager();
```

I then use the `cache` from various threads like so:

```
transactionManager.begin();
cache.put(KEY, VALUE);
...
transactionManager.commit();
```

Is this the most effective/performant way I could achieve this, or should I consider a different class or are there some tuning options that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinispan development is more focused on the clustered setup; local caches are rather a special case, and therefore their implementation may seem somewhat heavier.

You've missed `builder.transaction().notifications(false)` - that could slice another percent, and disables the ability to use transaction listeners. Also, you can experiment with `budiler.transaction().useSynchronization(true)`, though with the dummy TM (which is used for invocation batching) it probably doesn't matter too much.

There's a cache mode optimized for local operations - [simple cache](http://infinispan.org/docs/8.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_simple_cache) but that does not support transactions. So, I'd say that this is pretty much all.